# Python - convert Tuple into String

Tags: python, mysql, string

I have a connection to my MySQL DB. 
And my program reads the Selected Objects and makes a tuple out of it (result)

```
a = """SELECT plates FROM plat"""
cursorO.execute(a)
connectionoracle.commit()
result = cursorO.fetchall()
print result
```

Now, I want to write the content of "result" into an other db.
I try this:

```
s = result

cursorM.execute("""UPDATE `anpr_localhost`.`plat` SET
`Plat` = %s
WHERE `ID` = 1;""", (s))
connectionmysql.commit()

cursorM.close()
```

This is simply not working, because result is a tuple and not a string.
I already tried

```
result.join(map(str, result), '.')
```

And different variations of this, but my Consule always tells me that tuple object has no function "join" and things like that.

How can I convert my tuple (result) to a normal string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result is a list of tuples, you can try to do the following:

```
results = [".".join(map(str,r)) for r in result]
print ".".join(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join after you have mapped  `".".join(map(str, result))`

```
result =(1,2,3,4,)
```

`print ".".join(map(str, result))`

`1.2.3.4`

Or if a list of tuples:

```
" ".join(".".join(map(str, s)) for s in result)
```

Comment: we are creating a string from the tuple not mutating the tuple.

Comment: the same principle applies, just iterate over the list of tuples

Comment: not of you iterate over and map/join the elements in the loop

Comment: what happens when you have more than one element in the tuple?